# How can i use destructuring to obtain the target property of a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, destructuring

I'm currently taking a test and the problem goes like this - Create **detectCardType**, **validateCardExpiryDate**, and **validateCardHolderName** functions. Each should take in a parameter and use object de-structuring to obtain the target property of the parameter.

This is what i have tried. I tried combining the arrow function but i don 't know how to go about to destructuring thing.

```
        const {target} = a;
      }
      const validateCardExpiryDate = ({b}) => {
        const {target} = b;
      }
      const validateCardHolderName = ({c}) => {
        const {target} = c;
      }
```

I keep getting
`You have not declared detectCardType as specified`

Comment: That is not a JS error - it's a test one.  Maybe the test will only accept a real function?   `function detectCardType(card) { const { type } = card }`

Comment: Your currently destructuring twice for each of those functions..  Once here -> `({b}) => {`  basically your destructuring your first parameter, and then you do it again here -> `const {target} = c;`   Are you sure that's what you meant to do?

Comment: @Alnitak I am to use only ES5 syntax

Comment: Your code appears to be missing the first line. Please [edit] it

Comment: @Keith Yeah, i want to destructure for different functions.

Comment: @Joshtom If you want to use ES5 only, then you can't use destructuring.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a little sandbox and play with some different object structures passed into some test functions and see what destructuring various steps returns

Comment: @Bergi - Okay. That means i will have to use the regular function then?

Comment: I get thanks @charlietfl

Comment: @Joshtom Oh, and no arrow functions either, that's right. But regular vs arrow doesn't matter, you couldn't use destructuring anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you copied wrong, but I don't see the top where you defined `detectCardType`.  Anyway, you're destructuring twice: once in the parameters list and once in the variable declaration in the function. You can just use one or the other, but using both looks for a `argument[0].b.target` for instance instead of just `argument[0].target` that you want.

Comment: Please how can i go about it, like destructuring once?

Comment: As others have said, don't use curly brackets in the function parameters. That's destructuring, so that it's setting the value of a, b, and c to the a, b, or c property of the passed object rather than the full object.

Answer (score 1):

```
const validateCardExpiryDate = (a) => {
        const {target} = a;
        return target;
}
console.log(validateCardExpiryDate({target:'some target'}));
```

Comment: or just `const validateCardExpiryDate = ({a}) => a;`

Answer (score 1):

A few options. 2nd is shortest (suggested by someone via edit) but IMO less readable. Third is just a regular function instead of an arrow function.

```
const detectCardType = a => {
  const {target} = a;
  return target;
}

// this style also works
const validateCardExpiryDate = {target} => target;

// as does this
function validateCardHolderName(obj) {
  const {target} = obj;
  return target;
}

const a = {target: 'answer'}
const b = {target: 'hello'}
const c = {target: 'world'}

console.log(detectCardType(a));
// "answer"
console.log(validateCardExpiryDate(b));
// "hello"
console.log(validateCardHolderName(c));
// "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This should work in this case ...

```
      const detectCardType = ({target}) => target
      const validateCardExpiryDate = ({target}) => target   
      const validateCardHolderName = ({target}) => target
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following method of function parameter object destructuring and you should be good to proceed with your test**

```
const detectCardType = ({target: card}) => {
    }
const validateCardExpiryDate = ({target: expiryDate}) => {
    }
const validateCardHolderName = ({target: holderName}) => {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should solve it:**

```
const detectCardType = ({target}) => {
    return target;
  } 

  const validateCardExpiryDate = ({target}) => {
    return target;
  }

  const validateCardHolderName = ({target}) => {
    return target;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Everyone that contributed, This solved it.
The mistake i made before was that i was ***destructuring*** twice.

```
const detectCardType = ({target}) => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require [explicit returns](https://medium.com/@josephcardillo/a-beginners-guide-to-arrow-functions-in-es6-part-1-187c45c6987c) this should work.

```
const detectCardType = ({target}) => {
        return target;
      };
```

**for [explicit returns](https://medium.com/@josephcardillo/a-beginners-guide-to-arrow-functions-in-es6-part-1-187c45c6987c) or shorthand use this**

```
const detectCardType = ({target}) => target;
```